# How do I export an Eclipse project with external JARs, images, sound files, fonts, dlls, etc.?

Tags: java, eclipse, lwjgl

I have a game that uses external JARs(for LWJGL and Slick), natives (dlls), and a resource folder (images, sound files, and TrueType fonts). How can I publish this game so that others can download and play it?

I tried exporting it as a runnable JAR, using WinRAR to add the resource folder, and using JarSplice to add external JARs and natives, but nothing happens when I run it.

[Here's an album of each step of what I tried.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cVH7.jpg)

I need a step-by-step tutorial, and I am not very experienced. Please help.

Comment: Check to make sure all of your file are where they belong.

Comment: @Coupon22 What do you mean? The game works fine in Eclipse. Where should the files go?

Comment: *"I need a step-by-step tutorial.."*  You are in the wrong place.  SO is a Q&A site rather than a place to seek a tutor.

Comment: I am asking if all of your class and resource files are in your jar file. Sometimes they make mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this link from LWJGL's wiki:
http://lwjgl.com/wiki/index.php?title=Distributing_Your_LWJGL_Application

It describes how to set up your classpath to include the necessary files (Natives/jars etc)

Comment: That's only for natives and JARs. What do I do with the resources(images, sounds, fonts, etc.)?

Comment: Oh sorry, to get images and other content you can use the getResource-method which returns a url to your resource.
So if you put an image in your jar in directory "img", the getResource should look like this:
`URL resource = this.getClass().getResource("/img/image.jpg");`

Now you can use the resource as a stream:
`InputStream is = resource.openStream();`
or in a File object:
`File file = new File(resource.getURI());`

Answer (score 0):

Easiest (for the user) is to:

1. Put all resources into Jars.  (Classes by package path, natives in the root of separate signed Jars, other resources anywhere that is convenient).
2. Create a JNLP launch file (much like a page to load an applet, but for a free floating app.)
3. Deploy the lot from link on a web site using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).